# How to force function to return int32 integers?

Tags: arrays, matlab, casting, mixed-integer-programming

I have a command in Matlab, that I defined, which should return integer values:

```
x = intlinprog(f,intcon,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```

I don't want to round the result. I want the values to be `int` from the start.

This is what I tried :

```
x = int32([0 0 0 0 0 0 0  ])   
x = intlinprog(f,intcon,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)

%// but this is not working, and not giving integer values.
```

Any idea how I can force `x` to be a matrix of `int` values and not `double`?

Comment: I heavily revised your question, please put some more time in formatting and formulating your question next time. This is not some simple online forum, but a serious Q&A site.

Comment: A really important thing you seem to be ignoring is that **linear programming methods do not work on discrete variables**.  There's an entire field studying Integer Programming and Mixed-Integer Programming algorithms for optimizing such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x` defined in

```
x = int32([0 0 0 0 0 0 0])
```

is overwritten by

```
x = intlinprog(f,intcon,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```

---

So you have three options:

1) cast `int32` outside your function:

```
x = int32(intlinprog(f,intcon,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub))
```

2) or inside

```
function [ output ] = intlinprog(...)
   ...
   ...

   output = int32( output )

end
```

Use [**`round`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) before, if you think it is necessary. Consider also [**`ceil`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html), [**`floor`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html) and [**`fix`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html).

3) Or finally, probably what you actually intended, use the pre-allocated array correctly:

```
x = int32( [0 0 0 0 0 0 0] )  
x(1:end) = int32(intlinprog(f,intcon,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub))
```

by `x(1:end)` you are **not** overwriting the previously defined `x`, but rather fill its array elements and therefore keep the data type. The output of your function and the pre-allocated array need to have the same size though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of `intcon` from the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html)
:

> Example: `intcon = [1,2,7]` means `x(1), x(2), and x(7)` take only integer values.

So if you want all elements of `x` to be integers you should set `intcon` to `1:numel(f)`.

Comment: Such a strange coincidence, that OP's user-defined function happens to have exactly the same name, and name and order of parameters, as a toolkit function...

Comment: I think most of the problems are solvable when a user learns how to refer to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab tends to convert integers into doubles before performing his computations and there is pretty much nothing you can do about, avoiding at the same time any sort of overcomplexity. You have to modify your function so that the result is type-casted back to `int32` once all the computations are performed. I never checked this fact, but since Matlab is basically a wrapper of Java, I fear it could work the same way: when floating point values are casted to integer values, they are basically truncated. Hence:

```
Float      Integer
10.87  ->  10
10.14  ->  10
```

This is why I suggest you to round the values before casting them using the [int32 function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int32.html) in order to avoid loosing too much precision:

```
function result = intlinprog(...)
    % Your computations here...
    result = int32(round(result));
end
```

**EDIT**

I checked that:

```
A = [
   10.53;
   10.01;
   10.44;
   10.87
];

int32(A)

ans =

  4×1 int32 column vector

   11
   10
   10
   11
```

and the result lets me suppose that a rounding to the nearest integer is internally performed before the type conversion. So you can just use:

```
function result = intlinprog(...)
    % Your computations here...
    result = int32(result);
end
```

without problems.

Comment: I have a hard time with your statement that "Matlab is basically a wrapper of Java". MATLAB is written in C and C++, and probably has components in Fortran still. the UI is Java since version 7 or so, and nowadays you can directly call Java methods. But the computations are not done in Java, and I'd be surprised if any of the language-related code (parsing, execution engine, JIT) is Java. Note that MATLAB was first released in 1984, and Java was first made public by Sun in 1995 (according to Wikipedia).

Comment: Both C and C++ cast floats to ints by truncating. Java has probably inherited that from C.

Answer (score 0):

You could round the doubles to integers

```
x = round(intlinprog(f,intcon,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub))
```

Comment: i dont want to reound the result .. i want the values to be int from the start